# Why request.remote_ip.encoding is ASCII-8BIT?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, encoding

The output of `<%= request.remote_ip.encoding %>` is `ASCII-8BIT`.

When I store the `request.remote_ip` value in SQLite, there is a "[Binary data inserted for `string` type on column 'remote_ip'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912285/binary-data-inserted-for-string-type-on-column-remote-ip/)" message.

So, should I 'force_encoding' before storing in SQLite? Or, is there a config I can make `request.remote_ip` default to `UTF-8` (or maybe `ASCII-7BIT`)?

```
OS X Lion
ruby 1.9.3p194 
Rails 3.2.8
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.2)
```

Comment: Are you still experiencing this? It is discussed here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2743 - I faced a similar issue but in my case the only option was to use force_encoding('UTF-8')

Comment: @HannesBenson maybe you can put your findings in an answer and so I can credit you.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and read the discussion here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2743 . My only way around it was to use force_encoding('UTF-8') to ensure that the remote_ip string encoding was utf-8.